# Uso NOT EXISTS em 2 subquerys

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tentei usar o `NOT EXISTS`, mas está trazendo os resultados que não existe na tabela `tb_pedidoproduto`, creio que o `LIMIT` não está funcionando:

```
SELECT produto.idproduto
      ,produto.nomeproduto
      ,produto.idcategoria
      ,produto.imagem
      ,produto.qtdmedida
      ,produto.valorproduto
      ,produto.idunidademedida
      ,produto.descricaoproduto
  FROM tb_produto AS produto
 WHERE produto.idcategoria = '2'
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT pedidoproduto.idproduto
                           ,SUM(pedidoproduto.qtdprodutopedido) AS qtdprodutopedido
                      FROM tb_pedidoproduto AS pedidoproduto
                     WHERE produto.idcategoria = '2'
                       AND produto.idproduto = pedidoproduto.idproduto
                     GROUP BY pedidoproduto.idproduto
                     ORDER BY qtdprodutopedido DESC LIMIT 6)
 ORDER BY produto.idproduto ASC
```

Basicamente o que preciso é subtrair os resultados do primeiro `SELECT` com os do segundo, tentei fazer um `SELECT` usando o operando `-`, mas não funfou também.

P.S.: Fiz uma pergunta já sobre isso, mas as respostas não ajudaram, e aparentemente se eu editar a pergunta ninguém irá responder, por isso fiz outra.

Comment: Só pra ver se eu entendi, você quer pegar os itens diferentes entre as duas querys?

Comment: Isso, quero pegar todos os produtos exceto os 6 que mais venderam(que são tragos pela subquery da tabela tb_pedidoproduto

Comment: já tentou trocar o Not Exist por Not In?

Comment: Aliás, qual banco de dados você tá usando?

Comment: Tentei, uso o mysql, e ele não está aceitando o NOT IN

Comment: "#1235 - Esta versão de MySQL não suporta ainda 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'"

Comment: Eita, alguma chance de atualizar o MySQL?

Comment: Já tentei, não deu certo

Comment: Da para fazer uma pequna demontração de como deveria funcionar? Tipo colocar uma tabela com alguns reggistros e o que deveria acontecer? Pois acho que da para resolver com joins

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seu problema esta no seu sub select.. Você precisar relacionar o sua tabela `tb_pedidoproduto` com a `tb_produto` isso dentro do sub select e só depois verificar se os ids são iguais `AND ProdutoSub.idproduto = produto.idproduto` nas duas tabelas. Veja como fica.

```
SELECT produto.idproduto
      ,produto.nomeproduto
      ,produto.idcategoria
      ,produto.imagem
      ,produto.qtdmedida
      ,produto.valorproduto
      ,produto.idunidademedida
      ,produto.descricaoproduto
 FROM tb_produto AS produto
 WHERE produto.idcategoria = '2'

   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT pedidoproduto.idproduto ,SUM(pedidoproduto.qtdprodutopedido) AS qtdprodutopedido
                      FROM tb_pedidoproduto AS pedidoproduto
                      join tb_produto AS ProdutoSub on ProdutoSub.idproduto = pedidoproduto.idproduto
                      WHERE ProdutoSub.idcategoria = '2'
                      AND ProdutoSub.idproduto = produto.idproduto
                      GROUP BY pedidoproduto.idproduto
                      ORDER BY qtdprodutopedido 
                      DESC LIMIT 6)

 ORDER BY produto.idproduto ASC
```

Garanta que seu sub select esta retornando os 6 que você não quer.

```
SELECT pedidoproduto.idproduto ,SUM(pedidoproduto.qtdprodutopedido) AS qtdprodutopedido
                      FROM tb_pedidoproduto AS pedidoproduto
                      join tb_produto AS ProdutoSub on ProdutoSub.idproduto = pedidoproduto.idproduto
                      WHERE ProdutoSub.idcategoria = '2'
                      --AND ProdutoSub.idproduto = produto.idproduto
                      GROUP BY pedidoproduto.idproduto
                      ORDER BY qtdprodutopedido 
                      DESC LIMIT 6
```